# SVG Error: error while updating property of 'd'

Tags: javascript, react-native, svg, victory-charts

Before i start i just want to mention that i tried some ways of solving this problem when i search the site for answer, couldn't make this work :(

As the title suggested i have a problem while i'm using React Native Victory graphs.
**To be clear: it works fine untill i press the button to display the graph again.**

for example this is the onPress im calling the graph with useState method:

```
<TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => {
        setBarChecked(true);
        setLineIsChecked(false);
        setLineChecked(false);
        setPieChecked(false);
      }}
    >
      <FontAwesome5 name="chart-bar" size={36} color="#0000FF" style={{ padding: 9 }} />
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

This is the graph code:

```
    <VictoryBar
      barRatio={0.8}
      style={{
        data: { fill: "#c43a31" }
      }}
      data={handleBarData()} //This function calculate data and return array
    />
```

After a graph icon is pressed its working
[![Working][1]][1]

After im pressing another graph, and then returning to graph i already pressed before, the app freeze and i get this error:

[![error][2]][2]

using "react-native-svg": "^12.1.0",

**Edit start here:**

HandleBarData():

```
  const handleBarData = () => {
    //Predicion Part Start here -----> Bar Graph!!//
    const arrayIncome = months.splice(0, 6);
    const fictionalIncome = [560, 150, 3870, 4000, 7860, 7840]; // Past Values
    const size = fictionalIncome.length;

    let i = 0;
    const diffrence = [];
    for (i; i < size; i++) {
      diffrence[i] = arrayIncome[i] - fictionalIncome[i];
    }
    //console.log("Diffrenec => ", diffrence);
    ///////////////////////////////////////////

    let j = 0;
    const difWithPower = [];
    for (j; j < size; j++) {
      difWithPower[j] = Math.pow(diffrence[j], 1 / 2);
    }
    //console.log("Power => ", difWithPower);
    ///////////////////////////////////////////

    let k = 0;
    const substract = [];
    for (k; k < size; k++) {
      substract[k] = difWithPower[k] - 1;
    }
    //console.log("Substract => ", substract);
    ///////////////////////////////////////////

    let h = 0;
    const growthRate = [];
    for (h; h < size; h++) {
      growthRate[h] = substract[h] / 100;
    }
    //console.log("Growth Rate => ", growthRate);
    ///////////////////////////////////////////

    let a = 0;
    const resultIncome = [];
    for (a; a < size; a++) {
      resultIncome[a] = parseInt(
        diffrence[a] * growthRate[a] + diffrence[a],
        10
      );
    }

    //console.log("Difference X Gr Rate => ", resultIncome);

    //Graph of Future Income Start here ----->//
    let nextYearMonths = [
      "Jan 21",
      "Feb 21",
      "Mar 21",
      "Apr 21",
      "May 21",
      "Jun 21",
    ]; //Present first 6 Months of the year.
    const futureIncome = resultIncome; //[348,53,1291,226,1306,424];

    const result = {};

    nextYearMonths.forEach((key, i) => (result[key] = futureIncome[i]));
    const barData = { ...result };

    const arr4 = new Array();
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(barData)) {
      arr4.push({ x: key, y: value });
    }
    console.log("Arr 4 ", arr4); //Fetch to Graph?

    return arr4;
  };
```

Console Log:

```
Arr 4  Array [
  Object {
    "x": "Jan 21",
    "y": 348,
  },
  Object {
    "x": "Feb 21",
    "y": 53,
  },
  Object {
    "x": "Mar 21",
    "y": 1291,
  },
  Object {
    "x": "Apr 21",
    "y": 226,
  },
  Object {
    "x": "May 21",
    "y": 1306,
  },
  Object {
    "x": "Jun 21",
    "y": 424,
  },
]
```

**Another edit**

```
 return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>גרפים לניתוחים כלכליים וסטטיסטים:</Text>
      <View style={styles.textRow}>
        <Text style={styles.explainBlue}>כחול</Text>
        <Text style={styles.explainGraph}>- תחזית הכנסות לשנת 2021</Text>
      </View>
      {/********************************* */}
      <View style={styles.textRow}>
        <Text style={styles.explainRed}>אדום</Text>
        <Text style={styles.explainGraph}>- ניתוח הכנסות שנת 2020</Text>
      </View>
      {/********************************* */}
      <View style={styles.textRow}>
        <Text style={styles.explainPink}>ורוד</Text>
        <Text style={styles.explainGraph}>- ניתוח סטטיסטי של שירותי העסק</Text>
      </View>
      {/********************************* */}
      <View style={styles.textRow}>
        <Text style={styles.explainGreen}>ירוק</Text>
        <Text style={styles.explainGraph}>- ייצא דוח הכנסות שנתי לאקסל</Text>
      </View>
      {/********************************* */}
      <View style={styles.chooseContainer}>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
              setPieChecked(true);
              setBarChecked(false);
              setLineChecked(false);
              setLineIsChecked(false);
            }}
          >
            <FontAwesome5
              name="chart-pie"
              size={36}
              color="#FF3399"
              style={{ padding: 9 }}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
              setLineChecked(true);
              setPieChecked(false);
              setLineIsChecked(false);
              setBarChecked(false);
            }}
          >
            <FontAwesome5
              name="chart-line"
              size={36}
              color="red"
              style={{ padding: 9 }}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
              setBarChecked(true);
              setLineIsChecked(false);
              setLineChecked(false);
              setPieChecked(false);
            }}
          >
            <FontAwesome5
              name="chart-bar"
              size={36}
              color="#0000FF"
              style={{ padding: 9 }}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
              handleExcel();
            }}
          >
            <FontAwesome5
              name="file-excel"
              size={36}
              color="#1D6F42"
              style={{ padding: 9 }}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.graphsPart}>
        {pieChecked ? (
          <VictoryPie //Graph that holds the most used service on the business.
            height={250}
            width={350}
            colorScale={["#FDB927", "#552583", "#ED174C", "cyan"]}
            data={handlePie()}
          />
        ) : lineChecked ? (
          <VictoryChart
            width={370}
            height={300}
            theme={VictoryTheme.grayscale}
            padding={{ left: 52, top: 20, bottom: 40, right: 26 }}
            domainPadding={{ x: 7 }}
          >
            <VictoryBar
              barRatio={0.8}
              style={{
                data: { fill: "#c43a31" },
              }}
              labelComponent={<VictoryLabel dy={30} />}
              data={handleFirstLine()}
            />
          </VictoryChart>
        ) : barChecked ? (
          <VictoryChart
            theme={VictoryTheme.material}
            domainPadding={{ x: 15 }}
            width={350}
          >
            <VictoryBar
              barRatio={0.8}
              style={{
                data: { fill: "#c43a31" },
              }}
              data={handleBarData()}
            />
          </VictoryChart>
        ) : null}
      </View>
    </View>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this happens when you pass no data to your SVG graphs in Android. iOS does not have this issue.

Please make sure `handleBarData()` is always returning data to display on Android. If no data is present don't show your graph or it will crash. Something like this:

```
// Assuming your data looks like this
const data = [
  {
    month: 'Jan',
    count: 200
  },
  ....
]

const data = handleBarData()
const isDataAvailable = !!data.find(el => el.count > 0)
if (!isDataAvailable) {
  return <NoData/>
}

return <MyGraph/>
```

If the above is not working for you, please add a `console.log()` screenshot of the result of `handleBarData()` here so I can see what is going on.

---

Edit: Ok I have still the same hunch and I would do the following. Instead of passing data as a function like so `data={handleFirstLine()}`, assign every data function to a variable: `const firstLineData = handleFirstLine()`. Then `console.log`that data and make sure that data **IS** available (i.e. that `x > 0`) . This issue happened to me and was very frustrating.

Comment: console.log added to the question and handlebarData function code

Comment: @OsherRevach Could you add your complete `render` function?

Comment: @OsherRevach please look at my edit. Refactor your code a bit so you can clearly see what's going. You can also use breakpoints of course.

Comment: Hey
I got a new error and im this close to throw my computer from the window: Malformed calls from js field sizes are different